# Android GridView selector not working. Also how to get gridlines for specific columns in GridView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I am building a Sudoku app on android. I want to populate the screen with 81 textViews. I am using a GridView for that. Some how my selector is not working. I have defined two xmls for background of text view. One for selected and unselected. I have a selector xml which I have called in the Gridview xml. But my text views are not selectable when i click on them.

Here are my xmls:
selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#4f7df2"/>
</shape>
```

unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#9C7F7F"/>
</shape>
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected"
    android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Also I want to further divide this into 9 grids. I want to divide it using grid lines so its evident to the user which grid he is in. How do I achieve that goal?

Here is my SudokuAdapter class

```
public class SudokuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public SudokuAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 81;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected));
        textView.didTouchFocusSelect();
        textView.requestFocus();
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
    } else {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    return textView;
}
}
```

I tried removing setBackground from above, then the selector working only for selecting the textview. I want the default background if not selected to be unselected.

Here is my activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sudoku_grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sudoku_grid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new SudokuAdapter(this));

} 
}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sudoku_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="9"
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even have to use an adapter for making it selectable.Your dataset is not changing. Just use a table layout and loop through the cells.

To make a textview selectable, use this.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to unselect it when i switch to something else.

Comment: To make it possible, loop through all the textviews and textView.setSelected(false) when a new textview is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
textView.setOnClickClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
private boolean stateChanged;
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(stateChanged) {
        // reset background to default;
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(circleOffDrawable);
    } else {
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(circleOnDrawable);
    }
    stateChanged = !stateChanged;
 }
});
```

You have to maintain the state of selected or if not selected 
**And** also in your adapter change the line of setBackground

```
textView.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));
```

As selector has both the properties so it will change it automatically for you.

Comment: setTextIsSelectable(true) makes the text selectable not the textview. It for copy-paste purposes.